# Firebase Android: What happens to authenticated user after app is uninstalled?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my android app I use firebase authentication (email/password) to authenticate users.

The app works in a way that when a user logs in I add to the database under his/her UID a flag called `logged_in` and set it to `true`, and when logged out I change the flag to `false`.

The structure ends like this:

```
Users
|
|----userID
     |
     |---name=.....
     |---logged_in = true
```

**Problem**

Now if I logged in to my app and uninstalled the app without signing out, and then reinstalled the app. I noticed that the user will be automatically signed out, and if this is the case I will end up with a user that signed out with his `logged_in` flag in the database set to `true`.

In others words I never had the chance to set the flag to `false`, because the user never signed out from the app.

**My question:**

How to overcome this problem, to always update the database when a user is automatically signed out (like my example case: where user uninstalls the app while still logged in)?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

in onDestroy(){ }  (MainActiviry)
change your logged_in == false;

Updating or deleting data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks for replying, but how does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding what it means for a user to be "logged in" to your app.  Logins are persistent, and they are not based on any sort of session.  Firebase Authentication internally manages the token that represents their login, and it gets refreshed periodically, or after the user stops using your app for some time.

You will never be able to fully guarantee that your app can trigger some of its code when the user uninstalls, wipes their device, or simply loses their device and never comes back to your app again.  Also note that your users can log in, and stay logged in, from multiple devices.

If you want to know if the user has stopped using your app for some time, you will have to record that in your database (probably by updating a field that indicates when was the last time they launched your app), and query the database (using a backend you control) to find out when that date/time becomes old enough that you are certain the user has left permanently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer doug, I just want to ask you this question: I am trying to allow only one user to login at a time so I save his/her status in the database as (true for logged in), and when he/she signs out I update the status to (false). When someone now try to log in from another device I will query the value of the status (if false I allow the login and if no I stop the user from logging in).....But the problem comes when one user logs in and uninstalls the app, because now the value is not updated and no one will ever login from this account again......any suggestion for my problem.